# have_posts() return false in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to show the last article on my theme for wp, so I wrote this code:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<div class="content">

<div class="pad group">

    <?php get_template_part('inc/page-title'); ?>

    <?php //echo var_dump(have_posts()); ?>

    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

        <?php if ( ot_get_option('blog-standard') == 'on' ): ?>

            <?php while ( have_posts() ): the_post(); ?>
                <?php get_template_part('content-standard'); ?>
            <?php endwhile; ?>

        <?php else: ?>
            <div class="post-list group">
                <?php $i = 1; echo '<div class="post-row">'; while ( have_posts() ): the_post(); ?>
                    <?php get_template_part('content'); ?>
                    <?php if($i % 2 == 0) { echo '</div><div class="post-row">'; } $i++; endwhile; echo '</div>'; ?>
            </div><!--/.post-list-->
        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php get_template_part('inc/front-widgets-bottom'); ?>
        <?php get_template_part('inc/pagination'); ?>
        <?php get_template_part('inc/picks'); ?>

    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php get_template_part('inc/front-widgets-top'); ?>

</div><!--/.pad-->
```

in the first part I get the header, in the `content` div I've opened a container called `pad group` and then with `page-title` I get the title of the page.

After this I check if there is post available (of course there are) with `if ( have_posts() )`, but the code in the condition is never executed, infact if you see I did a `var_dump` of `have_posts()` and this return `false`.

I saw already other question here with the same topic but I cannot find any solution for me. Some of these questions ask about a `if` condition not properly closed but I checked all the files included (`header` also) and I can't find any problem.

Someone maybe have a better eye than me? Thanks for any help.

Comment: the function `have_posts()` might work on a archive page template... if you're using archive page template, make sure the naming conventions of the file conforms to the standards... check the code in the `archive.php` file

Comment: @CrystalPaladin I forgot to say that this is the index.php

Comment: are those posts normal wordpress posts? or are they custom posts? coz `have_posts()` will work only for normal wordpress posts... and also check your `functions.php` to check for any hooks that tamper with the wp query...

Comment: @CrystalPaladin yes are normal wp post, if I do `var_dump($query->have_posts());` this return true, so I really don't understand why happen

Comment: @CrystalPaladin Oh, I noticed that if I do this: `<?php query_posts('post_type=post'); if ( have_posts() ) : ?>` working, but why I need to specify the post type before the query?

Comment: I suspect some hooks in functions.php or somewhere in `inc/page-title.php` that modifies the wp query changes the post_type... or some plugin that misbehaves... you could try disabling plugins one by one and pinpointing the exact issue

Answer (score 1):

Try to use custom WP_Query.

```
// WP_Query arguments
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page'         => '1',
    'cat' => <CATEGORY_ID>
);

// The Query
$query = new WP_Query( $args );

// The Loop
if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        $query->the_post();
        // do something
    }
} else {
    // no posts found
}

// Restore original Post Data
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Code above will fetch one recent post from category you set via **CATEGORY_ID**.

If you like to further customise you query, you can use [WP_Query generator](https://generatewp.com/wp_query/), or check [WP_Query Class docs](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query).

Comment: I tried your code and when I `var_dump($query->have_posts());` I get true, I don't understand why have_posts doesn't working

Comment: That's because have_posts() function use global $wp_query variable. That variable is set differently, according to page you currently try to open in browser, and more specific template file in theme that is used to generate HTML for browser. [Here is template files hierarchy] (https://codex.wordpress.org/images/1/18/Template_Hierarchy.png). Long story short, some template files generate query, that have no content to fetch.

Comment: If it's in index.php, call `wp_reset_query();` before `var_dump(have_posts());` and check the result. BTW. You do not need to echo `var_dump()` ;)

Comment: nothing is changed, note that I call `<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>` before, but I don't think that this is the problem

Comment: Mayby try `rewind_posts();` ?

Comment: Also return false

Comment: I just notice you said that `query_posts('post_type=post');` fix problem. Disable all plugins you use and check the result. The cause may be in some point specific plugin or theme modify default query, and do not reset query to default state.

Comment: I've no plugin installed, I'm on localhost webserver

Answer (score 0):

try this-

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',//or you can add custom post type
    'order' => 'DESC'
);
$posts = get_posts($args);
if(!empty($posts)){
    foreach($posts as $post => $post_val){
        echo $post_val->post_content;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, if I use post_type working, as I said before, but I don't know why I need to specify this when the post is available

Comment: post from which post type you want to show if in your backend  there are two or more custom post type then u have to specify

Comment: then remove 'post_type' => 'post',

Comment: I mean  `<?php /*query_posts('post_type=post'); */ if ( have_posts() ) : ?>`

Comment: or check your theme single.php file

Comment: Unfortunately not, sorry. I need to fix the code that I post. Single.php is for article not for index.php

Comment: check your single.php